# How to create slide effect on button when clicked on one from another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know how to create slide effect like website stripe.com on buttons or tabs

[image: design of tabs in stripe.com]

Here is My design

[image]

Front end Code

```
 <nav id="sw-nav-developers" class="nav flex-md-column justify-content-between justify-content-md-start nav-pills nav-pills-light nav-fill"><a class="nav-item nav-link text-md-left active" data-toggle="tab" href="#payasyou-tab"><i class="icon fas fa-code"></i> HTML Structure</a> 
                    <hr class="mt-2">
                    <a  class="nav-link accent" style="color:#db78dd;font-weight: 600;text-transform: uppercase;">Software Coverage <i class="icon fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></a>

                   <a class="nav-item nav-link text-md-left " data-toggle="tab" href="#basic-tab"><i class="icon fas fa-code"></i>Basic</a>
                   <a class="nav-item nav-link text-md-left" data-toggle="tab" href="#pro-tab"><i class="icon fab fa-sass"></i> Pro</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link text-md-left" href="#premium-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon fas fa-retweet fa-rotate-90"></i> Premium</a> <a class="nav-item nav-link text-md-left" href="#exclusive-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Exclusive</a>
                    <hr class="mt-2"><a class="nav-link accent" style="color:#45b2e8;font-weight: 600;text-transform: uppercase;">Hardware Coverage <i class="icon fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></a>

                    <a class="nav-item nav-link text-md-left " data-toggle="tab" href="#oneyear-tab"><i class="icon fas fa-code"></i> HTML Structure</a> <a class="nav-item nav-link text-md-left" data-toggle="tab" href="#twoyear-tab"><i class="icon fab fa-sass"></i> SASS compiler</a>  </nav>
```

now i achieve sliding effect on hover but how to achieve this on button click or active.

CSS which i used

```
nav#sw-nav-developers a.nav-item {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 12px;
        font-family: Camphor,Open Sans,Segoe UI,sans-serif;
        text-align: left;
       cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
      -webkit-transition: color .3s;
      transition: color .3s;
     height: 34px;
      transition:.5s;
    }
    .nav-pills-light .nav-link.active:before {
          content:'';
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background:rgba(50,50,93,.11);
            overflow:hidden;
            z-index:-99;
            transform:scaleY(0);
            transform-origin:bottom;
            transition:transform 5s ease-in-out;
     }
     .nav-pills-light .nav-link.active:active:before {
        transform:scaleY(1);
            transform-origin:top;
    }
```

please help me out to achieve this for reference you can see same effect on stripe.com

Answer (score 0):

Having trouble understanding what you are asking, but if you say you managed to achieve this with :hover, and what to achieve this also with click or active, you need two things:

1. also add an **:active** and/or **:focus** rule. Example :

```css
    .nav-link.active:before ,
    .nav-link:active:before ,
    .nav-link:hover:before  ,
    .nav-link:focus:before  {
        /*your same code here */ 
    };
```

2. Add code to add the .active class to the current element, and remove it from the siblings (which i'm guessing you have already managed to do).

Also, this rule is not right : it refers to when the **.nav-link** has a class of **.active** and also the user is clicking (holding click down) on the element - that's what **:active** means.

.nav-link.active:active:before { ... }